# Cannot create file, access is denied

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I made a program where you enter information and it has a button `'Save'` which saves to a certain file. When I test saving it, Windows 7 gives me an error saying `Cannot create file c:\Users\ADMIN\DESKTOP\INFOSAVER - Access is denied`. I am running my program as  Administrator and I have set the ownership details of the file and folder its in. I know its not my programs fault, its windows.

Anyone care to help?

**ps:** My 'My windows is not genuine' because I had to format my PC a few weeks ago, resulting in me installing my old windows cdkey which is no longer valid.

I am not going to pay for what I have already paid for.. Do you think this is whats making it not work?

Comment: `I am running my program on Administrator`? Do you mean that you are running as the user administrator, or as a user which can elevate his/her rights? (e.g. someone from the admin group)?

Comment: As to genuine windows. If you had a legal CoA (aka 'cdkey') then you can just reinstall it after a re-installation on the same system. Something is either wrong with your postscript part, or you do not have a legal CoA, or you have an OEM version and changed motherboard, or ...

Comment: Is `c:\Users\ADMIN\DESKTOP\INFOSAVER` the path used by the actual program or is it `c:\Users\ADMINISTRATOR\DESKTOP\INFOSAVER`

Comment: You old key is still valid come back when your installation is geniune

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly happens when you put in your 'old key?' You should be able to activate it again. Try running 'slui 4' and choose the phone option. Then explain to Microsoft that you had an issue and reloaded your OS. They will help you activate.

For you application, have you tried running as administrator? Right click your app and choose 'Run as Administrator.'